# How to get the id of a react material-ui component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have been trying to get the id value of a react material-ui component for hours and i still cant figure out why i cant retrieve properties of components like in plain java script. Any particular reason why i cant retrieve the id like this?

This is my code

```
class MenuComponent extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
     super(props);

  }

  buttonclick =(event) => {
    let {id} = event.target;
    console.log(id);
  }

   render(){
     return(
       <div>
           <Menu>
             <MenuItem primaryText="Free Parking" id="freeparking" onTouchTap={this.buttonclick}  />
           </Menu>
       </div>
     );
   }
}
```

Comment: r u getting any error ??

Comment: No, im getting an empty string

Comment: did u install `injectTapEventPlugin`, it is required with material ui components ?? for onTouchTap events. check this `jsfiddle` you can pass the id along with the click event, and receive it in the function args check this: https://jsfiddle.net/1v4zh0p9/

Comment: @MayankShukla yes i have installed injectTapEventPlugin and it is being used at app file where react router is used.

Comment: check the `jsfiddle`, alternate way of accessing the id of element :)

Comment: why do you need id on MenuItem? What are you trying achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the ID directly into your handler without relying on DOM events/attributes...

```
<MenuItem primaryText="Free Parking" onTouchTap={() => this.buttonclick("freeparking")}  />

buttonclick =(id) => {
  console.log(id);
}
```